# Passing JSON String all the way from Java to JSTree messing up JSTree's interpretation of string

Tags: javascript, string, jstree

On my Java Servlet Server:

```
String javaJsonStr = "'Simple Root Node 1','Simple Root Node 2', {'text' : 'Root Node 3','children' : ['Child 1','Child 2']}";
request.setAttribute("jsonStrAttr", javaJsonStr );
```

On my HTML page:

```
<script>
<%String javaStr = request.getAttribute("jsonStrAttr").toString();%>
var dataJson;
dataJson = new String("<%=javaStr%>");
$('#myTreeId').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [ dataJson ]
} });
</script>
```

And this is what I get.
[image]

Understand I've tried many variations: without the toString(), no quotes in this line `dataJson = new String("<%=javaStr%>");`, single quotes, escape characters.  Sometimes I get just that first "Simple Root Node 1".  But I never get a good tree of nodes and child nodes.

Undertand I'm viewing this in a crummy Eclipse localhost browser, but I have no reason to believe it'll go any better on a real browser.

Answer (score 0):

In 'data' you pass ['some string from a request'].

" is not equals to ' in json, to have a valid json: always use "

You have to find a way ton build a valid JSONArray in java (I realy think there are a lot of api's who can do the job), in the end you need to have a json like this

```
[
    "Simple Root Node 1 ",
    "Simple Root Node 2", 
    {
        "text" : "Root Node 3", 
        "children" : [
                         "Child 1",
                         "Child 2"
                     ]
    }
]
```

Then stringify the JSONArray and send it.

Get that String and transform it to a JavaScript object with JSON.parse :

```
const arrayFromJson= JSON.parse('<%=javaStr%>');
console.log("JavaScript array:", arrayFromJson});
// ... treat array and do stuff ...
```

Comment: I find it difficult to follow your answer.  The only difference between your string and the one I'm showing is that you use double quotes where I use single quotes.  The rest of the information you give seem periphery to my question.  Would you please elaborate.

Comment: The problem is you pass a string uncastable as json.
You have to format your string like this : "[\"Simple Root Node 1 \",\"Simple Root Node 2\",{\"text\":\"Root Node 3\",\"children\":[\"Child 1\",\"Child 2\"]}]" in JAVA, then pass it and after JSON.parse the string to get a real JavaScript object